# Perl regular expression replacement

Tags: regex, perl

The code is here. My question is since `$1` is `Fred` and this is a replacement, which means replacing `fred or barney` with `Fred`, why cannot the answer be like `I saw FRED with FRED.` i have no idea for what's going on here. Thank you for your answer!

```
$_ = "I saw Barney with Fred.";
s/(fred|barney)/\U$1/gi; # $_ is now "I saw BARNEY with FRED."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` refers to "whatever the first capturing group captured".  So when `(fred|barney)` matches `fred`, that's what `$1` contains, but when it matches `barney`, that is then what `$1` contains.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. It first saw `barney` and then saw `fred`, `$1` remains the last value.

Answer (score 1):

Because the capturing group not only captures the string `Fred` but also `Barney`. So if the regex engine see `Fred`, it replaces immediately with Uppercase FRED and if the engine sees Barney, it replaces it with Uppercase Barney.